# How to get element of component without using listener such as onChange?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would presumably like to run the function auto_grow on useEffect but i require the element to be passed in to edit its values. Is there a way I can pass in the element without a listener so useEffect can make use of it?

I tried document.getElementById but that returns just the textarea and scrollHeight isnt a property.

**Code:**

```
function ChatInput(props){
    const [text, setText]=useState();

    function auto_grow(element){
        element.target.style.height = "5px";
        console.log(element)
        element.target.style.height =(element.target.scrollHeight)+"px";
        
        
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        setText(props.answer)
        
    },[props.answer])
        return(
            <>
            <Container style={{paddingTop:'.5rem'}}>
                <InputGroup>
                    <InputGroup.Text>Bot</InputGroup.Text>
                    <Form.Control onLoad={auto_grow}style={textareaStyle} as="textarea" value={text} aria-label="Chat Input"/>
                </InputGroup>
            </Container>
            </>
        )
    
}

const textareaStyle = {
    resize: "none",
    overflow: "hidden",
    minHeight: "50px",
    maxHeight: "1000px"
}



export default ChatInput;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a ref to get the underlying element.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
// ...
function ChatInput(props) {
    const ref = useRef();
    // ref usage example:
    useEffect(() => {
        ref.current.style.height = ref.current.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }, []);
    // ...
    return (
        // other elements...
        <Form.Control ref={ref} as="textarea" value={text} aria-label="Chat Input" />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are mistaken.  scrollHeight is a property of each dom element

```js
var element = document.getElementById('test')
console.log(element.scrollHeight)
```

```html
<body>
<div id = "test">xxx</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ill get a undefined error. So ill just have to make a catch to check if content is loaded. Ill give it a try and get back to you. Thanks